# Оптимизация функции парсинга шахматной нотации на C#

Tags: c#, парсер, оптимизация, шахматы

Думаю нет ничего страшного в том, что я оставил бы такой код и не пытался бы его оптимизировать, функция работает и она не особо длинная; но все же на будущее я хотел бы узнать от более опытных программистов как я мог бы оптимизировать её, чтобы было, возможно, меньше ненужного кода?

Итак, **суть функции** - спарсить входную строчку с ходом, записанным с помощью шахматной нотации, в строчку, понятную обычному человеку (например - "Ng1-f3" => "Конь g1 на f3" или "Pa7-a8Q" => "Пешка a7 на a8 и превращается в ферзя").

---

Код:

```
public static string MoveParser(string move)
        {
            if (move == "0-0") return "Короткая рокировка";
            if (move == "0-0-0") return "Длинная рокировка";

            Dictionary<char, string> figures = new Dictionary<char, string>
            {
                { 'P', "Пешка"},
                { 'R', "Ладья"},
                { 'N', "Конь"},
                { 'B', "Слон"},
                { 'Q', "Ферзь"},
                { 'K', "Король"}
            };

            var figure = figures[move[0]];
            var startCell = move[1].ToString() + move[2].ToString();
            var endCell = move[4].ToString() + move[5].ToString();

            var pawnToFigure = "";
            if (move.Length == 7)
                pawnToFigure = " и превращается в " + figures[move[6]];

            return figure + startCell + " на " + endCell + pawnToFigure;
        }
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: какой код ты считаешь _ненужным_?

Comment: @Grundy, возможно переменные startCell и endCell можно как-то переписать, чтобы было меньше  кода + мб проверку на превращение пешки в фигуру можно написать более просто и кратко

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Самая главная оптимизация здесь - это вынос создания словаря из метода, чтобы он при каждом вызове не создавался заново. Слона то вы и не приметили. :)

```
private static readonly Dictionary<char, string> _figures = new Dictionary<char, string>
{
    { 'P', "Пешка"},
    { 'R', "Ладья"},
    { 'N', "Конь"},
    { 'B', "Слон"},
    { 'Q', "Ферзь"},
    { 'K', "Король"}
};

public static string MoveParser(string move)
{
    if (move == "0-0") return "Короткая рокировка";
    if (move == "0-0-0") return "Длинная рокировка";

    string result = $"{_figures[move[0]]} {move[1..3]} на {move[4..6]}";
    if (move.Length == 7)
        result += $" и превращается в {_figures[move[6]]}";

    return result;
}
```

Все остальное - интерполяция строк и `System.Range` из C# 8.0

```
Console.WriteLine(MoveParser("Ng1-f3"));
Console.WriteLine(MoveParser("Pa7-a8Q"));
```

```
Конь g1 на f3
Пешка a7 на a8 и превращается в Ферзь
```

Comment: да, спасибо, так действительно лучше